# (Non-)Completeness for connected pointed $\infty$-groupoids

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

In an example in Lurie's *HA*, it is implied that the $\left(\infty,1\right)$-category of *connected* pointed $\infty$-groupoids is presentable. But it is not closed under homotopy pullbacks (e.g., $\Omega(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$), and every presentable $\left(\infty,1\right)$-category is complete. Why is this not a contradiction? Is there a distinction between homotopy limits and $\left(\infty, 1\right)$-limits in this case?

Comment: Which example? I think the point here is that the inclusion of pointed connected spaces into pointed spaces does not preserve limits.  Instead, there is a right adjoint $G$ taking a space to the connected component of the base point,  and limits are computed by taking the limit in pointed spaces and then applying $G$.

Comment: @PhilTosteson It's Example 1.4.1.4. I'm not sure why the issue is non-continuity of the inclusion functor, since not all homotopy pullbacks exist in pointed connected groupoids.

Comment: No, they do, the category of pointed connected $\infty$ groupoids has all limits. They're just not formed the same way as in the category of all pointed $\infty$-groupoids (rather, they are computed by taking the connected component of the basepoint). For example, you can check that your pullback of $pt\rightarrow S^1\leftarrow pt$ is just $pt$ in connected land.

Comment: Achim and I are saying the same thing.  This phenomenon is common in ordinary category theory .  There is a subcategory that is not closed under limits in the ambient category---but this doesn't mean that the subcategory fails to have limits.  E.g the category of reduced schemes has limits,  but it is not closed under limits in the category of all schemes.   Dually,  the category of sheaves admits colimits, but is not typically closed under colimits in the category of presheaves.

Comment: It's especially confusing because older category-theoretic literature sometimes used the phrase "closed under limits" to *mean* "has limits".  I assume they meant something like "the representables are closed under limits in the presheaf category".

Comment: Another extremely silly example: the full subcategory on the point has all limits, but is not closed under limits in pointed sets...

Comment: Wait, Denis, why not? Isn't the limit of any functor with constant value the point even in the ambient category still the point? It's the terminal object after all...

Comment: @AchimKrause damn, I was thinking of colimits. Ignore everything I said...

Comment: @DenisNardin I guess you also meant sets not pointed sets?